# Simple probability with fair coins

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

So I have a very simple probability question here.

> An Urn contains five coins of which three are fair, one is two-headed, and one is two-tailed. A coin is drawn at random and tossed twice.
>
> a) What is the probability that 'head' appears both times?
>
> b) If 'head' appears both times, what is the probability that the coin is two-headed?
>
> c) Suppose that 'head' appears both times. Draw another coin from the urn (Which has four coins remaining). What is the probability that the second coin drawn from the urn is a fair one?

I already got parts a and b. It's part c I am having issues with. My idea was to use:
\begin{align}
\text{P(2nd fair) }&\text{= P(1st coin fair)*P(2nd coin fair)+ P(Two headed coin)*P(2nd coin fair)}\\
&= \frac{3}{5}*\frac{2}{4}+\frac{1}{5}*\frac{3}{4}\\
&=0.45
\end{align}
I ignored tails since I Want two heads and that can only happen with a fair coin and the two headed coin. Is my reasoning right? I just need to clarify this. Thanks!

Comment: It's easy to see that the answer can't be $0.45$, because no matter which type of coin is drawn first, there will be either $2$ or $3$ fair coins left, so the probability the second coin is fair must be somewhere between $2/4$ and $3/4$, i.e. somewhere $0.5$ and $0.75$. So it is definitely not as low as $0.45$. See my answer for the full explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote the type of the first coin drawn by a symbol $s\in \{F,T,H\}$, where $F$ stands for fair and the other two for tails and heads, respectively. We can compute the conditional probability that the second coin is fair given the type $s$ as follows:
$$
\mathbb P(\text{second is fair}\mid s=F)=\frac{2}{4},\quad \mathbb P(\text{second is fair}\mid s=H)=\mathbb P(\text{second is fair}\mid s=T)=\frac{3}{4}.
$$
Now we can use [Bayes' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem) to finish. The probabilities of seeing two heads for each of the three coin types $F,T,H$ are
$$
\frac{1}{4},\quad 0,\quad 1,
$$
respectively. Combining these allows us to find the  distribution of the type, $s$:
$$
\mathbb P(s=F)=\frac{1}{5},\quad \mathbb P(s=T)=0,\quad \mathbb P(s=H)=\frac{4}{5}.
$$
Consequently,
$$
\mathbb P(\text{second is fair})=\frac{1}{5}\cdot \frac{2}{4}+0\cdot \frac{3}{4}+\frac{4}{5}\cdot \frac{3}{4}=\frac{7}{10}.
$$

Comment: How did you get $\frac{1}{5},0$ and $\frac{4}{5}$? I don't see how Baye's rule is applied there.

Comment: Bayes' rule says that the conditional probabilities $\mathbb P(A\mid B)$ and $\mathbb P(B\mid A)$ are proportional. What it means in this case is that to find the distribution of $s$, you just need to find by what constant to rescale the probabilities $\mathbb P(\text{two heads}\mid s=F)$, $\mathbb P(\text{two heads}\mid s=T)$, $\mathbb P(\text{two heads}\mid s=H)$ in order to get a probability distribution. Here, the constant is $\frac{4}{5}$, since before multiplying by a constant the probabilities sum to $\frac{1}{4}+0+1=\frac{5}{4}$.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but yes, this makes sense. Thank you very much :) .